# edit a localstorage array

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I am currently working on a project for my course, we are using an API to create an ecommerce website, the products are included in the API.
On the product page I have used this :

```js
}

let colors = document.querySelector("#colors");

colors.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  console.log(colors.value);
});

let quantity = document.querySelector("#quantity");

quantity.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  console.log(quantity.value);
});

let submit = document.getElementById('addToCart');

submit.onclick = () => {
  var basketItem = {
    productname     : `${productname}`,
    productcolor    : colors.value,
    productquantity : quantity.value,
  }
  console.log(basketItem);
  checkStorage()
  //Check if local storage is empty
  function checkStorage() {
    if (localStorage.getItem(`${productname}` + colors.value) === null) {
      const local = localStorage.setItem(`${productname}` + colors.value, JSON.stringify(basketItem));
    } else {
      console.log("this product is already in basket");
      //> add current quantity value to it's quantity
      // HERE
    }
  }
}
```

For example when I add 5 black 'Kanap sinopés' to my basket I have this in the local storage:

```js
{productname: "Kanap Sinopé", productcolor: "Black", productquantity: "5"}
productcolor: "Black"
productname: "Kanap Sinopé"
productquantity: "5"
```

So far I have the if/else function that tells if the product has already been added to the basket but I would like to edit the quantity of this item in the local storage when they click "add to basket' to avoid creating another item in the localstorage.
How can I edit this information in the localstorage please?

Comment: You just have to overwrite the whole localStorage array with the new array that includes the new product.

Answer (score -1):

You will need to get the information out, alter it as needed, and then overwrite the existing value. So in your case, your `checkStorage()` function could look something like this:

```js
function checkStorage() {
  if (localStorage.getItem(`${productname}` + colors.value) === null) {
    const local = localStorage.setItem(`${productname}` + colors.value, JSON.stringify(basketItem));
  } else {
    console.log("this product is already in basket");
    const existing = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(`${productname}` + colors.value));
    // Convert quantities to number values so we can guarantee we do
    // numerical computations.
    const existingQuantity = parseInt(existing.productquantity, 10);
    const basketQuantity = parseInt(basketItem.productquantity, 10);
    // To keep the schema consistent, convert the resulting number back to
    // a string.
    existing.productquantity = (existingQuantity + basketQuantity ).toString();
    const local = localStorage.setItem(`${productname}` + colors.value, JSON.stringify(basketItem));
  }
}
```

We can then even refactor the function to be a little [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)er:

```js
function checkStorage() {
  const key = `${productname}${colors.value}`;
  let item = localStorage.getItem(key);
  if (item === null) {
    item = basketItem;
  }
  else {
    console.log("this product is already in basket");
    item = JSON.parse(item);
    // Convert quantities to number values so we can guarantee we do
    // numerical computations.
    const existingQuantity = parseInt(item.productquantity, 10);
    const basketQuantity = parseInt(basketItem.productquantity, 10);
    // To keep the schema consistent, convert the resulting number back to
    // a string.
    item.productquantity = (existingQuantity + basketQuantity).toString();
  }

  localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(item));
}
```